# Wix bundle of third party exe and new msi cant figure out detect conditions

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bundle, exe, bootstrapper

I am trying to figure out how to bundle a third party software .exe with my wpf app .msi. I created a wix installer project and have that building my .msi file correctly and now I want to bundle that with a third party exe. The only problem is that it requires a detect condition. I found the install product identifier in windows registry but I just need help building that into a condition that I can use. Here is what i have so far in my bundle.wxs file.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
   <Bundle Name="MyProject.Bundle" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="f52749fb-8d37-4800-9913-e6ee897b50f9">
      <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
      <Chain>
         <ExePackage Id="ThirdPartySoftware" SourceFile="Drivers\ThirdPartySoftware.exe" Vital="yes" />
         <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyProject.Installer\Installs\MyProject-1.0.0.0-Release-x64.msi" />
      </Chain>
   </Bundle>
   <Fragment Id="Product_PreReqs">
      <Property Id="ThirdParty" Secure="yes" Value="0">
         <RegistrySearch Id="ThirdPartySearch"
                         Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\ThirdParty"
                         Type="directory"
                         />
      </Property>
      <Property Id="ThirdPartySub1" Secure="yes" Value="0">
         <RegistrySearch Id="ThirdPartySub1Search"
                         Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\ThirdParty\ThirdPartySub1"
                         Type="directory"
                         />
      </Property>
         <Property Id="ThirdPartySub2" Secure="yes" Value="0">
            <RegistrySearch Id="ThirdPartySub2Search"
                            Root="HKLM"
                            Key="SOFTWARE\ThirdParty\ThirdPartySub1\ThirdPartySub2"
                            Type="directory"
                            />
      </Property>
         <Property Id="ThirdPartyVersion" Secure="yes" Value="0">
            <!-- 3.07.0044 -->
            <RegistrySearch Id="ThirdPartyVersionSearch"
                            Root="HKLM"
                            Key="SOFTWARE\ThirdParty\ThirdPartySub1\ThirdPartySub2"
                            Name="Version"
                            Type="raw"
                            />
      </Property>
      <Property Id="ThirdPartyUninstallVersion" Secure="yes" Value="0">
         <!-- 3.07.0044 -->
         <RegistrySearch Id="ThirdPartyUninstallVersionSearch"
                         Root="HKLM"
                         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{B122EBFB-4345-4AE3-90AE-99C8B9E3F02C}"
                         Name="DisplayVersion"
                         Type="raw"
                         />
      </Property>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have looked at the wix documentation on their website and searched all over Stack Overflow, Google, and YouTube. I have found results in all of these places that mention detect conditions but I havent found anything explaining how to create the condition or how to take these searches and put them into variables for the condition.